# IBM xForce API with PHP and json

Tags: php, json

ive been trying this for some time and im currently learning about API's etc.
Now i am trying to connect my application to IBM xForce to get the client IP health..

Ive been trying small variants of this code:

```
function GetAuthToken(){

$Url = "https://api.xforce.ibmcloud.com/auth/AnonymousToken/";


//send request:
$Client = curl_init($Url);


curl_setopt($Client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


//response:
$Response = curl_exec($Client);




//decode:
$Authorized = json_decode($Response);

$Token = $Authorized->token;
return $Token;
}

echo GetAuthToken();
```

I really have no idea about what im doing wrong

Here is the typical response i get when accessing the url in a browser:

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyVW5pcXVlSUQiOiIyNWM0OTlkMS0yMjk4LTRjY2YtYTI1ZS1kODZmYzVlZGU2OTQiLCJ0eXBlIjoiYW5vbnltb3VzIiwiaWF0IjoxNDQxNjA5MTE0LCJleHAiOjE0NDE4NjgzMTR9.6a8YsIGfkIxghO7ypvMY7S9LQsR2CuiKO6b-jSAxm3U"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong. As the name of the function indicates: you just retrieved an authorization token, which you need in order to get access to the public API. The public API queries (except `/auth/anonymousToken`) require a valid authorization token in each request’s headers.

Once you have extracted that token, you must include it with the value "Bearer " (note the space at the end!) followed by the token string as the value of its Authorization header.

Example: 
`curl -I 'https://xforce-api.mybluemix.net/swagger.json/ipr/history/1.2.3.4' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,' -H 'Authorization: Bearer $Token' -H 'Accept:application/json'`

These authorization tokens persist for three days. You can periodically revitalize existing tokens with the `/refresh` query or request a completely new token with the `/auth/anonymousToken` query.

If you use one of the libraries, you can save an appropriate header entry in the `xfeOptions` structure:
`xfeOptions.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $Token`

More about this:

- [IBM X-Force Exchange API Documentation](https://api.xforce.ibmcloud.com/doc/)
- [Introduction to the X-Force Exchange API](https://securityintelligence.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-x-force-exchange-api/)

***Update after comment from Kristian Hareland:***

`curl_setopt($Client, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` is your friend.

The connections is closed, because cURL can't verify the SSL certificate. The quick fix is to add `curl_setopt($Client, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`, the proper fix is described [here](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/).

```
function GetAuthToken(){

$Url = "https://api.xforce.ibmcloud.com/auth/AnonymousToken/";

//send request:
$Client = curl_init($Url);

curl_setopt($Client, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($Client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($Client, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//response:
$Response = curl_exec($Client);

//decode:
$Authorized = json_decode($Response, true);
$Token = $Authorized["token"];

return $Token;
}

echo "XF-API-Token: ". GetAuthToken();
```

Comment: My problem is that i do not get any value when echoing out 'GetAuthToken();' any ideas?